# My app front page is not showing anything except the heading

Tags: android, android-layout

**The Following Code is From MainActivity.xml file**

Only the Heading "G.K. Quiz" is appearing on the app.
It's just the same 10 questions with 3 radiobutton options to choose from and all this inside a ScrollView Linear Layout. I don't understand what the problem is. I'm new to android coding. Is it something to do with the ScrollView?? ThankYou in Advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   tools:context="com.example.android.generalquiz.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16sp"
        android:fontFamily="casual"
        android:text="@string/quiz"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="@string/first"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/ans1"
        style="@style/margin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/largest" />

    <RadioButton
        style="@style/margin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/longest" />

    <RadioButton
        style="@style/margin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/none" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="@string/second"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <RadioButton
        style="@style/margin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/seconda" />

    <RadioButton
        style="@style/margin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/secondb" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/ans2"
        style="@style/margin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/secondc" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="@string/third"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <RadioButton
        style="@style/margin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/thirda" />

    <RadioButton
        style="@style/margin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/thirdb" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/ans3"
        style="@style/margin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/thirdc" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="@string/fourth"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <RadioButton
        style="@style/margin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/fourtha" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/ans4"
        style="@style/margin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/fourthb" />

    <RadioButton
        style="@style/margin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/fourthc" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="@string/fifth"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/ans5"
        style="@style/margin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/fiftha" />

    <RadioButton
        style="@style/margin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/fifthb" />

    <RadioButton
        style="@style/margin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/fifthc" />
 </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDOab.png)

Comment: set scrollview height to something not wrap_content

Comment: like match_parent?

Comment: Your code seems to work fine when i tried.... and you an use `android:layout_height="match_parent"`  for ScrollView

Comment: I tried removing ScrollView altogether and replaced it with just a LinearLayout just to see if anything different happens but that also did not help. Its the same blank screen after the heading. So it must not be a problem of the ScrollView..?

Comment: The Code runs properly on the Android Studio but not on the devices, I tried multiple devices too.